# Get IP address of virtual network interface

Tags: go, networking

How can I get the IP address of a virtual network interface? This is an interface that looks like this:

```
lo:0: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 192.168.40.1  netmask 255.255.255.255
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
```

This is how I retrieve the IP address of a regular interface:

```
func GetInterfaceIpAddr(interfaceName string) (string, error) {
    var (
        ief      *net.Interface
        addrs    []net.Addr
        ipv4Addr net.IP
    )

    ief, err := net.InterfaceByName(interfaceName)

    if err != nil { // get interface
        log.Info("InterfaceByName failed")
        return "", err
    }

    addrs, err = ief.Addrs()

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    for _, addr := range addrs { // get ipv4 address
        if ipv4Addr = addr.(*net.IPNet).IP.To4(); ipv4Addr != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    if ipv4Addr == nil {
        return "", errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("interface %s doesn't have an ipv4 address\n", interfaceName))
    }

    return ipv4Addr.String(), nil
}
```

When I pass `lo:0` to the above, `net.InterfaceByName` fails with this error: `route ip+net: no such network interface`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux you could use https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink to get the IP addresses and labels.

This is a library that allows a Linux user-space program to communicate with the kernel via the netlink interface. It can be used to configure interfaces and routes, etc. or to retrieve the informations.

In Linux 2.0 there was the alias concept, which was formed by adding a colon and a string to the interface name when executing ifconfig. Since Linux 2.2, which introduced the possibility of having multiple addresses per interface, this concept has been deprecated, see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/alias.txt

Nevertheless, it is backward compatible, and via the Netlink interface you can retrieve the attributes including IFA_LABEL, which represent interface names (including alias names).

Since the question explicitly refers to the aliases, it is assumed that one IP address per interface name is configured.  If necessary, however, it could easily be added to return multiple IP addresses per interface, since of course the full `NetlinkRouteAttr` data is returned. This would then cover both cases.

This could look something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/vishvananda/netlink"
    "github.com/vishvananda/netlink/nl"
    "net"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    interfaceName := "lo:0"
    ip, err := GetInterfaceIpAddr(interfaceName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s -> %s\n", interfaceName, ip)
}

func GetInterfaceIpAddr(interfaceName string) (string, error) {
    ifis, err := interfaces(netlink.FAMILY_V4)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    ip, ok := ifis[interfaceName]
    if !ok {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("%s not found", interfaceName)
    }
    return ip.String(), nil
}

func interfaces(family int) (map[string]net.IP, error) {
    req := nl.NewNetlinkRequest(syscall.RTM_GETADDR, syscall.NLM_F_DUMP)
    msg := nl.NewIfInfomsg(family)
    req.AddData(msg)
    messages, err := req.Execute(syscall.NETLINK_ROUTE, syscall.RTM_NEWADDR)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ifis := make(map[string]net.IP)
    for _, m := range messages {
        msg := nl.DeserializeIfAddrmsg(m)
        attrs, err := nl.ParseRouteAttr(m[msg.Len():])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        var ip net.IP
        var label string
        for _, attr := range attrs {
            switch attr.Attr.Type {
            case syscall.IFA_LOCAL:
                ip = attr.Value
            case syscall.IFA_LABEL:
                label = string(attr.Value[:len(attr.Value)-1])
            }
        }
        if ip != nil && label != "" {
            ifis[label] = ip
        }
    }
    return ifis, nil
}
```

A test on Ubuntu gives:

```
lo:0 -> 127.0.0.2
```

This is probably not yet what you need in detail. But it could be a first step in the right direction.

Comment: Amazing answer. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think I spot two immediate problems with your code:

1. An interface alias like `lo:0` isn't an "virtual interface", it's just a label applied to an address. You'll find the address associated with the main interface (`lo` in this case). The output of the `ifconfig` command is misleading and you shouldn't be using it; use `ip addr` to see you interface address configuration.

   For example, if I create an "alias interface" with `ifconfig`, like this:

   ```
   # ifconfig lo:0 192.168.123.123/24
   ```

   I see the following output from `ifconfig`:

   ```
   # ifconfig
   lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
           inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
           inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
           loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
           RX packets 504291  bytes 72010889 (68.6 MiB)
           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
           TX packets 504291  bytes 72010889 (68.6 MiB)
           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

   lo:0: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
           inet 192.168.123.123  netmask 255.255.255.0
           loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
   ```

   Whereas `ip addr` shows me:

   ```
   # ip addr show lo
   1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
       inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet 192.168.123.123/24 scope global lo:0
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   ```

   There you can see that the secondary address is actually associated with device `lo` with some extra metadata. If we ask for the interface address on `lo` in Go:

   ```
   ief, _ := net.InterfaceByName("lo")
   addrs, _ := ief.Addrs()
   fmt.Printf("addrs: %v\n", addrs)
   ```

   We get:

   ```
   addrs: [127.0.0.1/8 192.168.123.123/24 ::1/128]
   ```

   So the answer to the first part of your question is, "use the primary interface name". But there's a second problem:
2. Interfaces can have more than one ipv4 address but (a) your code only returns a single address and (b) your code will only ever return the *first* address.

The appropriate solution here depends on what you're trying to do:

- Just pass your code an explicit address rather than trying to discover it from the interface name. Since an interface can have multiple addresses -- and in fact that's relatively common -- there's not really a great way to determine "the address of an interface".

  I think in most cases this will be the best option.
- Find (or write) code that can fetch all the metadata associated with an in interface, so that you can look for a specific `label`.
- Just call `ip addr` and parse the output. You can get JSON output by calling `ip -j addr show`.

Comment: Solution #2 was the best option for us. Solution #1 would change how we deploy.